# How can I populate multiple within mongoose-paginate-v2

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have tried using this way but it's not working. populate the only webmail_account_id
but other fields are null. How can I fix this?

```
const searchText = "Build";
const options = {
      page: req.pageNumber,
      limit: 5,
      forceCountFn: true,
      //sort: { date: -1 },
      populate: 'webmail_account_id social_account_info company_info sender_info business_setup_info reply_id tag_info',
      lean: true,
      collation: {
        locale: 'en'
      }
    };

await EmailModel.paginate({
      $and: [{company_id: req.user.company_name_id}, {reply_type: {$exists: false}}],
      $or: [{subject: {$regex: searchText}}, {from: {$regex: searchText}}]
    }, options)
      .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        if (Object.keys(doc).length > 0) {
          result(doc);
        } else {
          console.log("Email Data Not Exists");
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is here.

```
const options = {
      page: req.pageNumber,
      limit: 5,
      forceCountFn: true,
      //sort: { date: -1 },
      populate: 'webmail_account_id social_account_info company_info sender_info business_setup_info reply_id tag_info',
      lean: true,
      collation: {
        locale: 'en'
      }
    };
```

If I change the option populate like this way then it works fine, check it out bellow.

```
populate: ['webmail_account_id', 'social_account_info', 'company_info', 'sender_info', 'business_setup_info', 'reply_id', 'tag_info'],
```